# Windows application to interface with Android app

Tags: java, android, windows

I ask you how to start for creating a Windows application written in JAVA that is based on a sqlite db in my android app. There's some framework already or I've to build from 0?

And how to connect via bluetooth Windows app and Android app?
To exchange data I was thinking to JSON. The problem is how to connect them.

Thank you

Comment: uhm, please rephrase your question and stick to one single question per thread.

Comment: In think some users thought your question demonstrates lack of research effort and therefore they voted down. It is just my guess though.

Comment: Please read [ask] to learn why you might have gotten downvoted. Generally the community likes to see some effort (code, errors, research, links). What have you found? What have you tried?

Comment: Nothing because I don't know from what start. I know create a swing interface, and ok. I was asking only if there was some framework, how to work in this case, what is better and what isn't. I was asking a point to start and suggestions for realizing that and how to connect and to communicate android app and windows app.

Comment: question 1: "...There's some framework already or I've to build from 0?"


question 2: "And how to connect via bluetooth Windows app and Android app?"



Reasons why I downvoted you: i can't understand what do you mean with "how to start for creating a Windows application ... in my android app" do you have a java app that you want to convert to an android app? or the other way around?

Comment: No, I haven't. I have an android app that I want to connect with a Windows application to share android app data with it. thank you for your explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the desktop application I would look at using jdbc to connect to say a MySql database ( should work on most desktop OS not just windows) .  Then you can investigate how to import the sqlite sb file into MySql 
a google search will throw up quite a few linksfor this